# Activate / Deactivate constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

In one of my view controllers I have two constraints that I need to activate or deactivate.

I've created a property to store the constraints. I have in my ViewController.h, the following IBOutlets:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *isReadOnly;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *isNotReadOnly;
```

I have dragged from the storyboard to add them there.

Then in the ViewController.m, I'm trying to deactivate and activate the constraints as follows:

```
_isNotReadOnly.active = NO;
_isReadOnly.active = YES;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

But nothing happens to the layout. Seems like the constraints are not switching.

Comment: At first glance, I don't know what might be wrong. But, are you doing this in the main thread? And did you confirm that the constraints have values?

Comment: Yes in ***viewWillAppear*** and yes I confirm that their are not nil.

Comment: That exhausts all my ideas for now. :(

Comment: Why are you accessing the underlying iVar instead of using the property; Don't use the _ unless you have a good reason for bypassing the setter/getter.  What happens if you change the initial active/inactive state in the storyboard?  Do you get the right layout?

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, just tried removing the _ but same result...